# Socket.io connected always false

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My **socket.connected** is always **false**, cannot emit or receive messages too.

> app.js

```
var app = require('./config/server');    
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

http.listen(80, function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
    console.log('Server client instagram_clone_v01 online');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    console.log("new user connected");
});
```

> server side

```
var sockets = io();
sockets.on('connection', function ()
{
    console.log("connected");
    sockets.emit("newPhoto");
});
```

> client side

```
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:80");
console.log(socket.connected);

socket.on('error', function()
{
    console.log("Sorry, there seems to be an issue with the connection!");
});

socket.on('connect_error', function(err)
{
    console.log("connect failed"+err);
});

socket.on('connection', function ()
{
    console.log("connected");
    socket.on('newPhoto',function()
    {
        load_posts();
    });
});
```

None of the "**on**"s are **received**, not even "**error**". So how can i make it work, please?

Comment: Any messages on the server side?

Comment: You're doing `console.log(socket.connected)` before without waiting for `socket.on('connection', ...)`

Comment: I don't think this explains why OP isn't getting connection or error messages.

Comment: No, the console.log("connected"); does not show up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've checked Your code locally.

So issue was that You're checking: `.on('connection',...)`  when it should be `.on('connect', ...)`

So try this fix:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log("Connected to WS server");

  console.log(socket.connected); 

  load_posts();
});

socket.on('newPhoto', function(){
  load_posts();
});
```

Comment: What if i changed to port to 3000? 
By the way, I'm using firefox

Thanks for the fast replay :]

Comment: @AnnyWalker can You change: `socket.on('connection', ...)` to `socket.on('connect', ...)`  ?

Comment: Just tried both 'connection' and 'connect', doesn't work for me and the 'connected' is still always false.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker put Your code somewhere and share with me

Comment: @num8er https://gist.github.com/terryjiang2020/522d3b2f185c13bd8582a081e1b272c1

Comment: @TerryWindwalker Your code seems correct, I’ve double checked socket.io serverside code and clientside. Can You tell in which place You check `socket.connected` ? I think there must be race condition - You check connected before succeeding.

Comment: @num8er After "formSocketIOConnectionWithAccessToken" is called, I called another function to check socket status and listen to certain events. At there I found connected is false.

Comment: @num8er Also I just tried adding "console.log('connected')" to the on connect function, that log never show up.

Comment: @num8er I the meantime I can see 5~7 different connections were created in the backend. And they keep disconnecting and creating new connections every 2~5 seconds.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker seems to be Your module not being mounted in angular code. Make sure to log every step, even constructor to be confident that it’s being injected correctly.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker Your if statement has logical issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236013/discussion-between-num8er-and-terry-windwalker).

Answer (score 1):

When I was building a basic socketio app using React frontend and Node Express backend, I came across a similar problem in v4. With the typical Node/React setup, your react app will live on port 3000 and your express server will live on port 5000, and according to the docs this results in you needing to set an open CORS policy to enable connections to the socketio server on port 5000.

> Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin
> Resource Sharing (CORS).
> [(docs)](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/)

I simply made sure my socketio definition was as such:

```
const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

and I Was able to connect from a my react app inside of a useEffect. I was seeing all of the expected logs thereafter.

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket = io('localhost:5000');
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('socket connected');
      console.log(socket);
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common but confusing error for users who are running a virtual device, where the URL have to be the local IP of the host machine or 10.0.2.2

make sure your socket connection go along with the above definition:

```
   `const socket = io.connect("http://10.0.2.2:5000");`
```